# Remove event target

Tags: javascript

I connect a script with the event handler when the output of the found data occurs. But after I look again for the data, the script connects again and the handler is hung a second time. How can this be avoided?

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-action='create']", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    newContactInput(this);
});
```

Comment: When do you want `newContactInput` to be callable? Only once ever for a particular element, or repeatedly *if there is no ongoing* `newContactInput`?

Comment: You can use `.one` instead of `.on` for event to occur only once

Comment: @CertainPerformance repeatedly if there is no ongoing newContactInput

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal but I will have two .one event handler

Comment: `newContactInput` is an asynchronous function, and you want to prevent the default action only when the async function is not in process? And you actually don't want to remove the element listening to the click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensure that `newContactInput` returns a `Promise` that resolves once it's completed. Then, on click, you can put the clicked element into a `Set`, and check that the element is not present in the `Set` before calling `newContactInput`. Once `newContactInput` resolves, remove the element from the set. For example:

```
const ongoingActions = new Set();
$(document).on("click", "a[data-action='create']", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // An action is still in progress for this element, return immediately:
  if (ongoingActions.has(this)) return;
  ongoingActions.add(this);
  newContactInput(this)
    .then(() => ongoingActions.delete(this));
});
```